# Component of the identity is generated by any connected neighborhood of the identity when the group is locally connected?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

I read a theorem that if $G$ is a locally connected group, then the component of the identity $G_0$ is generated by any connected neighborhood of $e$.

It goes like: Let $V$ be a connected nbhd of $e$, $H$ the generated subgroup of $V$. For any $g\in H$, $gV$ is a connected nbhd of $g$ in $H$, so $H$ is open. Thus $H$ is closed as an open subgroup of a topological group. Since $H$ is closed and open, it is the union of the connected components of its points.

So since $e\in H$, $G_0\subseteq H$. Why should equality follow though? This is Theorem 10.21 in Peter Szekeres' A Coure in Modern Mathematical Physics.

Comment: I think there's no equality.  The inclusion is enough to prove the theorem.

Comment: If your group operation is continuous, which it probably is, then I think there is equality: $ V $ is connected and then by continuity so is $ U=V \cup V^{-1} $ and all $ U^{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} $. But then also $ H = \cup_{n} U^{n} $ is connected (as the $ U^{n} $ are nested).